# CodeIgniter Error 404 on root domain using PHP CGI

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

So, today I upgrade PHP and apache on my server to version PHP 5.4 and Apache 2.4.
And then I noticed on one domain using older version of codeigniter (I've try to echo CI_VERSION but it shows nothing) is showing error 404 on the root domain. But typing domain.com/home works fine. (home is my default controller). Typing any other controller also working fine. But domain.com shown error 404.

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

    #This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|apc\.php|assets|nivo-slider|hr|stm|elearning|docs|adminer|favicon\.ico|file|flash|tinymce|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 /application/errors/404.php
</IfModule>
```

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['index_page'] = "";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";
```

routes.php

```
$route["default_controller"]    = "home";
$route["error_controller"]      = "error";
$route['scaffolding_trigger'] = "";
```

I've trying change uri_protocol to QUERY_STRING & REQUEST_URI but still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by adding `DirectoryIndex home` on my .htaccess.